# Marriage clarification!

Tags: marriage, sin, kaparah-atonement

I was once told, that marriage clears one’s sins, though I doubt it’s that simple.

Could someone please explain to me the actual perimeters. Does it need to be a kosher wedding, does the Chattan and kalah  need to make a resolve to never go back to those sins, is up to a limited age for the chattan I.e it has to be before 21,… ect.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/475826/jewish/Day-of-the-Wedding.htm as per opening paragraph https://outorah.org/p/39266/ Yerushalmi Bikkurim 3:3, Yevamot 63b

Comment: @rosends, Thank you!

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79187/759

Comment: @rosends,I’ll ask you.So in other words one can be a complete rasha, I.e sleep with as many woman you want, Jewish or not, another man’s wife or not, eat whatever whenever you want, even say HaShem name in vain, be completely forgiven by shamayim. That does not sound right. There has to be a catch- and is it only on the first marriage, Or anytime you get married? I’m baffled by the fact that HaShem wants us to behave though gives an open loophole to do as you please and marriage will take care of everything.  Now for the small things you don’t even have to be married the dark ocean of Teshuva

Comment: http://images.shulcloud.com/440/uploads/Rabbi_s_Drashot/Yom-Kippur-Sermon.pdf A wedding day is like a personal Yom Kippur which is mechaper, but only along with proper teshuva. For discussions of what this really means, try these resources: https://www.midreshetmoriah.org/torah/view.asp?id=890 https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/818607/rabbi-azarya-berzon/masechet-yoma-85b-the-kappara-power-of-the-sair-of-yom-kippur-and-of-teshuva/

Comment: @rosends, So why do I need the mini when, supposedly they can go to the big one, and there’s tachnun, there’s a lot of other ways to repent a sin why do I need to put the most special time in life to get a pardon from HaShem? Whole ancestors from both sides of the wedding may show up to the wedding (to some opinions) they don’t need to attend the day I’m repenting, they don’t show for the actual YK,  RSh, Pass. We don’t want to scare people away from teshuva, does not work also, as they can do teshuva after marriage, like everyone else that needs to do teshuva afterwards.

Comment: @rosends, I was made aware that not everyone fasts on a wedding day, Sephardic customs is to not fast. So what about then?

Comment: @jonathan I think you approach the power of teshuva from the wrong angle. It is about having an additional opportunity, not an additional burden. Some days push us more powerfully to do teshuva. Some days help us see what can be. While we try, every day, to seize the chance to improve and repent daily, watershed moments afford us a clearer vision of how we can repent. This raises, not lowers the sanctity of the day. Why do we say "slach lanu" in ma'ariv AFTER Y"K if we have just repented? Because we are always repenting.

Comment: @rosends, Though that still does not answer the question,(the fact is)  before a wedding was annulling one’s sin through a fast. Now the fast is removed, so we’re at square one. Now the question is, how does it remove all the sins for sefardím who don’t fast.

Comment: I don't think that fasting, without teshuva would do anything. Simple cessation of eating isn't the point. But fasting as a show of spiritual exploration and teshuva is powerful.

Comment: I've always assumed that it is about the effect that your spouse has on you.  I know that personally there are many things that I struggled with before I got married that I'm doing far better at now and I attribute that to the extra chizuk that my wife gives me.  To me, it felt very much like a fresh start and the idea seemed natural.